# Determine minimum number of "invisible squares" to cover all markers on a map?

Tags: math, mapping, postgis

I have a map full of markers corresponding to GPS coordinates, represented as a PostgreSQL + PostGIS database table using "geography" type for the GPS column.

Imagine, if you will, one semi-transparent square on top of each of these points corresponding to 1x1 mile, based from the centre, often intersecting with each other.

I'm trying to determine the minimum number of such "squares" and their GPS coordinates, so that they "cover" all of the markers with a minimum of 25 meters to the nearest border.

If it makes it any easier, the positions of these "squares" don't have to match the positions of any of the markers.

The purpose of this is to attempt to cut down the number of API requests to a "houses for sale" service significantly, since most of the positions are close to each other and the API takes a 1x1 mile square "bounding box" as the input for each call. It would be insanely wasteful to call the API many times for basically the same area when maybe 1 or 2 times would do it if I can first figure out where these imaginary "squares" go.

I get the feeling that this is considered a "known, common and solved" problem, but so far, I've not been able to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Flip the problem on its head: the minimum number of squares is whatever you want it to be. Create a perfectly aligned, non-overlapping grid of squares, that covers the area you want, and then use it to make your API calls.

Comment: It is not clear how your API is supposed to work. Imagine you have a solution for this problem on the server, how the client would know which squares to ask for without knowing all the locations beforehand? I don't think you can do better than @jsanalytics suggests for a generic problem. And if your problem is more specific - provide more details (such as your imaginary API signatures and its usage by the client given the problem is already sovled)

Comment: I don't understand your comments whatsoever. Did you read my question? I thought it was obvious/implied that this has to be automated? The markers on the map will change with time and this is nothing that can be manually done.

Comment: Nobody said anything about doing it manually... you did...! :)

Comment: Please read BEFORE replying.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but it seems like you have no idea what you are doing and are just being rude, both here and at PostGIS irc-channel.

You give no information about your api.
What is creating your maps?
Is it a wms-service or what?

What most people would do is setting up a mapservice with a tile cache. Then the mapservice will pich the tiles needed for each house you want to show ( or multiple houses).

The tiles will be prepared o will be created on the fly. But they will be cached for next time.

So, I think you should read up on things like 
MapServer
Mapnik
MapCache
Mapproxy
GeoServer

That is not a complete list, but might give you some ideas about what it is that you want